# Printing design view in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is something I used to be able to do a while ago, but can't seem to get it to work now. I've googled everything I can think of on this subject. Here is my issue.

I am trying to print the design view of a web page I am building in Visual Studio. I am just working on the front end design right now. The back end still needs work and will error out on build, which is fine for now, I haven't gotten to that part yet.

I simply want to go to File, Print and print out the design view with images, layout, etc. When I go to print, the Print button is greyed out and does not allow me to print.

Can someone please show me how I can use the print feature? I've seen several extensions available for printing in color. I don't care about that. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and am building a .aspx page.

Comment: Is it an option for you to take a screenshot of the design view and then printing it out?

Comment: Nope. It's a 30 page document. I supposed I could screenshot each page, but that would be a pain.

Comment: I don't know if this is an option or not but when you debug in a browser you should have the option to print from there.

Comment: I won't work in a browser yet b/c I've only done the front end.